# minify code creates syntax problem python

Tags: python, syntax-error, minify

I am trying to minify code to save stress on my hard disk computer. This caused syntax error. I am not sure if token or comment is illegal and raising the error.

The original version worked. However, when I have try to unminify the minified original, it raises an error.

**CODE (minified)**

```
""" Title:TicTacToeAuthor:GNDate:12Version:1""";player_symbol='X';ai_symbol='O';board=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ', ' ',' ']];while True: print("{} {} {}\n{} {} {}\n{} {} {}\n".format(board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2],board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2],board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]));row=input('row? ');
```

**Expected Output:** 'row?'

But the actual output is Файл

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: **C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\gn\GN.py**, line 1, pos 136, строка 1
"""
```

Comment: Edit your question because it's unreadable

Comment: ok will do, i hope you enjoy.

regards

GN

Comment: "to save stress on my hard disk computer" This might be a reasonable approach if your harddisk is from the 80th. A simple Python script is no stress for any drive produced in this millennium.

Comment: I am using embedded system. Not many bytes for sharing brother. I can spare no bytes as there are very few bytes for consumption.

Comment: When I post this code into IDLE, it says that the syntax error is at `while True:` with `while` highlighted, and the character position of 136 agrees. The Python reference says (at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) "Several simple statements may occur on a single line separated by semicolons." That seems to imply that compound statements (such as one introduced by `while`) can not.

Comment: Thankyou very much, regards. I will just put on new line ). @BoarGules You are very smart man. Wil very much appreciate your comment. WING IDE has very limited debugging potential and will cause much confused. . Very good!!

Regards
GN
Founder of Impero Software Foundation
AND
GN opereator 
AND 
CCC SCHOOL ADMIN
AND 
CCC SCHOOL TEACHER
AND
CCC HEAD PHP DEV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` keyword has to be at the beginning of the line.